# i.s.client.config.discovery.NodeChecker : Error executing NodesInfo

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes

When I am deploying my application through jenkins job , I am getting an error, although deployment is successful. The error is related to elastic search connection.
i.s.client.config.discovery.NodeChecker  : Error executing NodesInfo!

Due to the error, elastic search is not connected with my application.

//JestClientObj = eSConnectionManager.getClient();
 configResult= JestClientObj.execute(uri).getSourceAsString();

This line of code is giving the exception.

Comment: Hi, can you provide me with some cluster information? Cluster enviroment,  kubernetes version, cluster network plugin/CNI would be appreciated. Is elastic search running as deployment or AWS service?

Comment: Elastic search is running as AWS service and version is 6.4.2 and Kubernetes version is 1.13.10.